# Return abitrary http code in symfony

Tags: symfony, apache2, fosrestbundle

Using symfony standard edition 2.6 and the FOSRestBundle, I'm throwing HttpException in my controller:

```
throw new HttpException(525, "An error occured", $e);
```

In the browser, it shows as an error 500.

When using 509 for instance, it's showing as 509.

What's wrong ?

Comment: Could you possibly add more code from the controller showing where exactly the error is coming from?

Comment: There are no errors : it's working fine with codes like 501, 502... 509, but not with 515, 550 which are converted back into "500".

Comment: what are those codes ? I couldn't find them here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
Maybe symfony doesn't recognize your codes and transforms them into a 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's a bug from symfony.

In the `HttpKernel->handleException()` method, only the status code is set:

```
if ($e instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
  // keep the HTTP status code and headers
  $response->setStatusCode($e->getStatusCode());
```

Then it tries to detect the `statusText` from the static array `Response::$statusText` but your code (530) is not defined, so it sets an empty text:

```
  if (null === $text) {
        $this->statusText = isset(self::$statusTexts[$code]) ? self::$statusTexts[$code] : '';

        return $this;
    }

    if (false === $text) {
        $this->statusText = '';

        return $this;
    }
```

I'm not sure that according to the [from the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2) the statusText (== reapon-phrase) is mandatory: it seems that is can be a space, so `HTTP/1.1 525`   (with two space) should be valid.

I think that apache (or the apache php binding) is modifying the status code when no status text is provided.